# Image encryption and decryption in android Java AES256

Tags: java, android, encryption, bitmap, aes

I am trying to fetch image from the camera & want to encrypt that bitmap and want to store that bitmap in internal storage in encrypted format and store path of that file in Sqlite DB also want to decrypt that file from path receiving from the Sqlite DB.

Using code following.

For Camera I Am using normal camera code
and found a bitmap `mImageCaptureBitmap`

for encryption and decryption we use following.

```
  private static String Key = "key@123";
   
 public static byte[] encryptString(String stringToEncode) throws NullPointerException {

        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getKey(Key);
            byte[] clearText = stringToEncode.getBytes("UTF8");
            final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(clearText);
            return encryptedValue;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decryptString(String stringToEncode) throws NullPointerException {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getKey(Key);
            final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(stringToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    Base64.DEFAULT));
            String decoded = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
            return decoded;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        int keyLength = 256;
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keyLength / 8];
        Arrays.fill(keyBytes, (byte) 0x0);
        byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int length = passwordBytes.length < keyBytes.length ? passwordBytes.length : keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, length);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        return key;
    }
```

for storing file in local

```
 public static void storeFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename, Context ctx
    ,String ID,String type){

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ctx);
        File directory = cw.getDir("IntegratorApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File file = new File(directory, filename);
        DatabaseHelper mdaDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        mdaDatabaseHelper.insertDocData(leadID,file.getAbsolutePath(),docType);

        try {
            StorageUnit.saveImage(ctx,bitmap,filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong but the image is not stored in db in encrypted format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then how is it stored?

Comment: Nowhere your encryption code is used for the bitmap.

Comment: You are trying to put something in the database before you created a file.

Comment: Your encryption implementation scares me for the following reasons: it is using a **static** IV, uses **no key derivation** (like e.g. PBKDF2) but a simple string to byte conversion and the input/output of your en-/decryption methods is a **string** [a bitmap is always a bunch of bytes]. Btw: the "Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00)" code is not necessary as "byte[] iv = new byte[16]" is generating byte 16 byte long arrays filled with 16 x00's. Kindly overthink your encryption as IMHO this implementation is **UNSECURE**.

Comment: @blackapps I am trying to store the image file in local folder of the device after encryption after that I am storing there path in db for feature use.

Comment: Well there is no code that tries to encrypt an image file. I said that before. So what is it that you want? And you are saving to database before there is a file. I said that before too.